# Use Firestore collection get() return type in a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to write some code that retrieves a collection from my Firestore instance.
My codebase uses the service repository pattern to keep business logic seperate from the code that retrieves data. For this reason I've made the following code:

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import { IOfficeRepository, TYPES } from "../common/types";
import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

@injectable()
export default class OfficeRepository implements IOfficeRepository {

  private fireStoreClient: Firestore;

  constructor(@inject(TYPES.FireStoreFactory) firestoreFactory: () => Firestore) {
    this.fireStoreClient = firestoreFactory();
  };

  public async getOffice(officeId: string): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>> {
    const officeCollection = "offices";

    const document = await this.fireStoreClient.collection(officeCollection).get();

    return document;
  };
}
```

What I'd like to do is return the value from the `get()` call to my service, in the service I will be performing checks and executing the business logic that I need.

The `get()` returns a `Promise<FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>>`, but I am unable to use this as a return type for the function in my repository. I just get the following error:

> Type 'QuerySnapshot' is missing the following properties from type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot': createTime, updateTime, data, exists, and 3 more.

I've already looked-up the error, but I wasn't able to find any solution or a post where someone was trying to return the result from the `get()` function before performing any logic on the result.

So my question is: How would I be able to make this setup work? Or is there something I am doing wrong with this setup? If so, what would be another approach to work this out while using the service repository pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declared return type of `QueryDocumentSnapshot` doesn't match the actual return type of `QuerySnapshot`.

This line of code:

```
const document = await this.fireStoreClient.collection(officeCollection).get();
```

performs a query for **all** of the documents in the officeCollection collection.  As you can see from the API documentation, [CollectionReference.get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#get) yields a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) object.  The entire set of documents will be available in the returned `docs` property.

It seems that you expect `getOffice` to return a single document instead.  I'm noticing that you never used the argument `officeId` to narrow down your query to just the one document you want.  Perhaps you meant to do something like this instead to get a single document using its ID?

```
const document = await this.fireStoreClient
    .collection(officeCollection)
    .doc(officeId)
    .get();
```

In this case, `document` will be a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) object.